# T-SQL : объединение строк выборки в одну строку

Tags: sql-server

Есть **SELECT**-запрос, который возвращает  5 строк.  Как можно их склеить в одну с каким-либо разделителем?

Сейчас у меня так работает: `select comment+',' from dbo.Reason  for xml path('')`

Может есть идея по-лучше?

**Спасибо.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ', ', '') + comment
FROM dbo.Reason

SELECT @result
```

Comment: Как вариант, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Чуть поменяла, в конце будет запятая:

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(max) =''

SELECT @result = @result  + comment+ ', '
FROM dbo.Reason

SELECT @result
```

Comment: Не подскажите, что вы поменяли, и почему в конце должна быть запятая?

Comment: Вероятно вы хотели помочь какому-то человеку? Автор вопроса вряд ли испытывает в этом потребность (посмотрите на дату поста), а для базы данных ценность ответа мала. Вероятно, вы решали похожу задачу (обычно в таких случаях лучше создать новый вопрос отдельно), но задачи такие близкие, что особого смысла нет.